# Apple In-App purchases with web applications?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, in-app-purchase, progressive-web-apps, razorpay

Is there any possibilities of using Apple In-App purchase in a progressive web app?

Actually I created an iOS app that completely runs a progressive web app in iOS Web view. My app got rejected for using external payment gateways. I used Razorpay SDK which integrated with the progressive web app.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Web Payment API:

https://whatwebcando.today/payments.html

Comment: Unfortunately, it only seems to be implemented by Chrome (as of December 2020).

Comment: No, Apple has support for their own Payment Request API. This is supported within iOS devices. Please actually read the page linked before posting a comment on an answer